# Using IOC to get UmbracoHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, autofac

I'm looking at improving performance on my Umbraco site (7.6.4) site and this line appears a lot:

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
```

I can add the UmbracoHelper to IOC (via Autofac)

```
builder.Register(c => new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current));
```

So i can do this, but should i be doing this, or could i get unexpected results?

Comment: It looks like you're replacing a direct `new` with a [per instance](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-dependency) factory method, which should amount to more or less the same thing as `new` performance wise. Assuming that `UmbracoContext.Current` has a per request lifespan, you'll want to add [`.InstancePerRequest();](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)` to the bootstrapping so that it doesn't invoke the factory multiple times if requested multiple times from the same request

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for umbraco + AutoFaq

```
 builder.Register(c => ApplicationContext.Current).InstancePerRequest();
 builder.Register(c => UmbracoContext.Current).InstancePerRequest();
 builder.Register(c => new UmbracoHelper(c.Resolve<UmbracoContext>())).InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think UmbracoHelper uses an interface, so if you want to use IOC to mock out umbraco dependencies, you'll probably run into trouble if you're not using Microsoft Fakes.

I don't know if it's best practice, but the way I've added the umbraco dependencies is by registering the different components of UmbracoHelper that do have an interface (The following code is Unity, not Autofac):

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

if (!Container.IsRegistered<IUmbracoComponentRenderer>())
    Container.RegisterType<IUmbracoComponentRenderer>(new InjectionFactory(o => umbracoHelper.UmbracoComponentRenderer));
if (!Container.IsRegistered<ITypedPublishedContentQuery>())
    Container.RegisterType<ITypedPublishedContentQuery>(new InjectionFactory(o => umbracoHelper.ContentQuery));
```

This way I can easily mock the interfaces without having to use Microsoft Fakes.

Comment: I don't know Umbraco, but it seems `UmbracoContext.Current` is specific to each [HttpRequest](https://our.umbraco.org/apidocs/csharp/api/Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.html), so it wouldn't be safe to capture in the process-wide IoC bootstrapping? (OP can register concrete classes in IoC as well, although as you point out, without interfaces or abstract base classes, mocking isn't possible)